# MAC OS X: find a computer independent path to a Dropbox local folder in excel formula or excel macro

Tags: macos, excel

I would like to define a computer independent path to access an Excel file stored in a Dropbox local folder from an Excel cell or from an Excel macro.
Currently if I refer to a file stored locally on a Dropbox folder either in my excel cell or in my excel macro, it will only work on one computer.
I would like the path to be generic such that it works from different computers with the same dropbox account.

Ideally I would like to make this path PC or MAC agnostic